# $C[0,1]$ is complete w.r.t. which norm(s)

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

$C[0,1]$ is complete w.r.t. which norm(s)

1. $\displaystyle\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|$
2. $\displaystyle\|f\|_1=\int_0^1|f(t)| \, dt$
3. $\displaystyle\|f\|_\infty^{0,1}=\|f\|_\infty+|f(0)|+|f(1)|$
4. $\displaystyle\|f\|=\sqrt{\int_0^1|f(t)| \, dt}$

I know 1 is true. But I don't know how to check completeness of norm base on know complete norm. How can I solve it?

Comment: @BenjaLim not on C[0,1].  The last one also isn't even a norm actually.

Comment: @BenjaLim Certainly not, for example 2 and 4 are different even if we restrict our attention to constant functions, as then $\|f\|=\sqrt{\|f\|_1}$.

Comment: @George: The first and third norms are equivalent (this is an easy proof). The fourth isn't a norm but you can find a sequence of continuous functions that converges to a discontinuous function in $L^1$ but not uniformly to prove that $C[0,1]$ is not complete with respect to 2 or 4.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if $x \leq 0 \leq \frac{1}{2}$} \\
 n\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right), & \text{if $\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}$}\\
1, & \text{if $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1$}. \end{cases}$$

Then $f_n(x)$ converges in the $L^1$ norm to the function that is $0$ on $[0,0.5]$ and $1$ on $(0.5,1]$. For $|f_n(x) - f|$ is a non - increasing sequence converging pointwise to $0$ and so

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int | f_n - f| = \int \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |f_n - f| = 0.$$

by the monotonce convergence theorem. Your "norm" in 4) is not a norm because it does not satisfy $||a\textbf{x}|| = |a| ||\textbf{x}||$.

Comment: You should move the discontinuity to the interior.  This sequence also converges in $L^1$ to the function $1$, which is continuous.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Ok wait I will make the discontinuity at a half.

Comment: Yep.  This way there's no element of the $L^1$ equivalence class which is continuous.

Comment: It shouldn't have been called $L^1$ if they haven't quotiented out by functions of measure zero yet, it should still be $\mathcal{L}^1.$ You really want to get from $\mathcal{L}$ to $L$ as soon as possible because the "norm" on $\mathcal{L}$ is only a semi norm.

Answer (score 3):

Norm $1$ and  $3$ are equivalent, so $C[0,1]$ is also complete in the norm $3$.

$||f||_{\infty}^{0,1}=||f||_{\infty}+|f(0)|+|f(1)|\le 3||f||_{\infty}$