# How to show $C_p^k([-\ell, \ell])$ is not a Banach space?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions

I need to show the space $$C_p^k([-\ell, \ell])=\{f\in C^k(\mathbb R; \mathbb C); f(x+2\ell)=f(x), \forall x\in\mathbb R\},$$ is not a banach space with the norms $$\|f\|_p=\left(\int_{-\ell}^{\ell}|f(x)|^p\right)^{1/p}, p\in [1, \infty).$$ Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hint: Show that you can approximate the function which is zero on $[-l,0]$ and one on $(0,l]$ arbitrarily well in that norm by functions in your space.

Comment: Also, see here for a hint on how you might go about this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388524/c0-1-is-complete-w-r-t-which-norms

Comment: Thanks I'll think about it =D

Comment: I can suppose $\ell=\pi$ for $C_p([-\ell, \ell])$ is isomorphic to $C_p([-\pi, \pi])$, right?

Answer (score 1):

> I can suppose $\ell=\pi$ for $C_p([−\ell,\ell])$ is isomorphic to $C_p([−\pi,\pi])$, right?

Correct. But it's not any harder to deal with general $\ell$ at once. For example, consider 
$$f_n(x)=(n^{-1}+\sin^2 (\pi x/\ell))^{1/2} \tag1$$
and observe that $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$, where $f(x)=|\sin (\pi x/\ell)|$ is not $C^k$ smooth.

Comment: Ok, I'll write the details =D Thanks